# can I have RSpec without a class for methods

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm just writing some algorithm methods that I don't want to put in a class. So I just put them in my ruby file.
But I cant figure out how to write test or more specifically use describe :xxx since I dont' have a class name to put after the main describe. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can put any string after the describe statement:

```
describe "Something You Want To Test" do
  # Your specs here
end
```

Comment: You should expand upon this answer and include info about file placement and types.